# Binding on the loose - providing null values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This one will be tough, since I would have to post a lot of source code. But maybe someone encountered similar problem.

Lately I've got a `NullReferenceException` in my code and I started to debug to inspect, what is causing it. This is what I've found:

- Call stack does not tell me much, there's a property setter, which code causes the `NRE`, a lot of internal WPF stuff and somewhere on the bottom a method, which (effectively) changes DataContext of a control.
- The setter is being called by a binding. The binding looks like the following:

  ```
  <MyControl SelectedClass="{Binding BaseClass, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  ```

  A null value is being set to `BaseClass` property of viewmodel, which causes the problem, because it is never expected to get a null value.
- The binding refreshes the values *mostly probably* due to DataContext change. Though, DataContext changes to a non-null value.
- I've used Inspector to get the current value of BaseClass property of the previous DataContext and the value is X.
- Also, I managed to inspect the current value of SelectedClass property of MyControl. It also is X, so actually there is no reason the binding passed a null value to the previous DataContext.
- I inspected the Binding, which is responsible for setting this null value:

  ```
  (BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(((MyEditor)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(editor.Children[0], 0))).cbBaseClass, MyControl.SelectedClassProperty)).ParentBinding
  {System.Windows.Data.Binding}
      base: {System.Windows.Data.Binding}
      AsyncState: null
      BindsDirectlyToSource: false
      Converter: {DebugConverter}
      ConverterCulture: null
      ConverterParameter: null
      ElementName: null
      IsAsync: false
      Mode: TwoWay
      NotifyOnSourceUpdated: false
      NotifyOnTargetUpdated: false
      NotifyOnValidationError: false
      Path: {System.Windows.PropertyPath}
      RelativeSource: null
      Source: null
      UpdateSourceExceptionFilter: null
      UpdateSourceTrigger: Default
      ValidatesOnDataErrors: false
      ValidatesOnExceptions: false
      ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors: true
      ValidationRules: Count = 0
      XPath: null
  ```

Now the question: What can be the possible reason for the binding to send a null value to source? OK, the DataContext is being changed, but the value goes to *previous* DataContext.

Following are the call stack frames between the action which causes the DataContext to change and my DebugConverter, which fires immediately before the setter.

---

```
    <Debug converter fires>
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertProposedValue(object value)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(object item, object value)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.UpdateValue(object value)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(object value)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties() Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged2(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.Type managerType)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs args)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.Refresh()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.EndDefer() Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.DeferHelper.Dispose()  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(System.Windows.Data.CollectionView view) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetItemsSource(System.Collections.IEnumerable value, System.Func<object,object> GetSourceItem) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool isASubPropertyChange) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool dependencySourcesChanged, bool initialValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnDependencyPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourceInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool isASubPropertyChange)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(System.Windows.DependencyObject source, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(object item)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject contextElement)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(System.Windows.DependencyObject source, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnInheritablePropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo info, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkLogicalChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceParent, System.Collections.IEnumerator logicalChildren)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>._VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, bool visitedViaVisualTree)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.VisitNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, bool visitedViaVisualTree)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement feParent, bool hasLogicalChildren)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.IterateChildren(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.InheritablePropertyChangeInfo>.StartWalk(System.Windows.DependencyObject startNode, bool skipStartNode)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.OnContentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool isASubPropertyChange) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool dependencySourcesChanged, bool initialValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(object o, string propName)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.Type managerType)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) Unknown
    <DataContext change>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the binding in the XAML-file? This way you should be able to see what actually gets set in the binding.

Comment: "This is not a valid location for a breakpoint", says the IDE. I usually use a debug converter, which does `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in both Convert and ConvertBack and I got information, that null is being passed by value during ConvertBack operation.